# SOLR/Lucene Server Location

Tags: solr

I am pondering the question of proper location of the SOLR server.
This is usually what we have today:
**Server Side:**

Node or RoR or IIS

**Client:**

Singe Page App or rendered by a server.

**DB:**

RDMBS - MsSQO, Postgre, MySQL or some other Relational database.

Thinking where to put a SOLR server. However I think, I am positive it should be not placed to be accessible from the internet, let alone accessible from the client. I think it should be behind main server, and the main server should send queries to SOLR and return to the client. Additionally, place SOLR behind the firewall and white list the server.

Is this good thinking or there is something else entirely that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs say](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity):

> First and foremost, Solr does not concern itself with security either at the document level or the communication level.

You are right: you should never have a publicly-visible Solr server for this reason. In our setup at work we have it firewalled so only our main webserver can access it (i.e. using whitelisting). As part of our API, requests for data therefore must go through the webserver, allowing us to authenticate users, as well as not give users free reign to execute whatever they want.

If you want to use the web client, you can always temporarily whitelist your IP and remove it afterwards. While it is possible for an attacker to spoof your IP and thus gain access, a hacker has to be very determined and explicitly targeting your application, has to know both the whitelisted IP and the Solr IP, and has to know all this for the short time it is whitelisted. Such a setup is therefore secure enough for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.